# How to use “ hwm ” (high-water marks) in zeromq ( v 3.2 )with C ？

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

The guide has explained what HWM means, but I don't understand this clearly. How to evalute hwm with message size/ subscriber performance? what is the relationship between them ?

Do ZMQ_XPUB and ZMQ_XSUB need hwm settings ?

Comment: You need to read the guide, your questions are addressed here: http://api.zeromq.org/3-3:zmq-socket

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific case where they don't work, leave the default HWMs (1,000 messages in send and receive buffers) in place.

Comment: Then what's the size of each message ?

Comment: One Publisher,one proxy, one subscriber